# Definition for "oral vaccination"

Tags: word-meaning

I want to write a definition for "oral vaccination" for a flashcard. I've come up with this:

> The practice of swallowing a vaccine, also applied to animals by the
>   use of baits, for example to prevent the spread of rabies among foxes.

Would that sound correct in form and content to a native speaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something simpler:

> oral vaccination--the practice of administering vaccine by mouth (rather than by injection)

Comment: +1 For taking out "swallowed."  Not all oral vaccines are swallowed - some are inhaled: http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2008/03/inhaled-tb-vaccine-more-effective-than-traditional-shot/ _"A novel aerosol version of the most common tuberculosis (TB) vaccine, administered directly to the lungs as an **oral** mist, ....."_

Comment: Thanks. I also like the "administering". I didn't know about the inhalation method — browsing some recent articles, it seems to me that it is still experimental, but I am just an everyman regarding medicine and (naturally) even more so regarding developments in the English-speaking world.